# System colour for inactive selected items in a listview?

Tags: .net, winforms, win32gui

Is there any system colour that define the background of a listview item when the control has no focus and the selection is not hidden? I'm not able to find it if so.

EDIT: I think it is the one listed in .Net as MenuBar (or ControlFace, or Control), but it would be nice if someone could confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always used the `SystemColors.Control` color for that and it's never not matched.

If using `VisualStyles`, you can try rendering it yourself:

```
var vsr = new VisualStyleRenderer(
    VisualStyleElement.ListView.Item.SelectedNotFocus);
vsr.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, rect);
```

Comment: Nice, I already knew about the VisualStyleRenderer, but never realized I could use it for this.

Comment: @Neverbirth Make sure to check `Application.RenderWitVisualStyles` to make sure it's supported.  If it's not, then fall back to the `SystemColors.Control`.